# Connect QML signal to PySide2 slot

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I have some expirience using Qt/C++ and now I want to switch to PySide2 + QML. I want to connect ui signals, such as clicking a button, to python slot

I have seen many examples, but they all differ, i guess PyQt/PySide is changing quickly now

Can you provide me modern and clean way of connecting a QML signal to PySide Slot? For example clicking a Button to printing some text in python console. Here's my simple code example

**main.py**

```py
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

def test_slot(string): # pseudo slot
    print(string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine('main.qml')
    exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Example"
        onClicked: test_slot("Test") //pseudo signal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practice in these cases is to create a QObject, export it to QML and make the connection there as it is also done in C++.

**main.py**

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class Foo(QObject):
    @Slot(str)
    def test_slot(self, string):
        print(string)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    app = QGuiApplication()
    foo = Foo()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("foo", foo)
    qml_file = "main.qml"
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, qml_file)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Example"
        onClicked: foo.test_slot("Test")
    }
}
```

<sub>**Note:** All C++/QML good practices also apply in Python/QML with minimal changes and restrictions.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The eyllanesc's solution is direct synchronous call of method `test_slot`. It is good when `test_slot` is small and fast. But if it includes a lot of operations, QML GUI will be suspended each time until `test_slot` is returned.

The mosth Qt-like way is slot-signal metaobject connection (see `#CHANGES` and `//CHANGES` below):

##### main.py

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Slot, Signal, Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

class Foo(QObject):
    @Slot(str)
    def test_slot(self, input_string : str):
        print(input_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    app = QGuiApplication()
    foo = Foo()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    
    #CHANGES: line excluded engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("foo", foo)
    
    qml_file = "main.qml"
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, qml_file)
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    
    #CHANGES: connect QML signal to Python slot
    engine.rootObjects()[0].test_signal.connect(foo.test_slot, type=Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

##### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    
    //CHANGES: declare signal
    signal test_signal(string input_string)

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Example"

        //CHANGES: emit signal
        onClicked: test_signal("Test string")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you please know how to make your solution working, when in main.qml is loaded another page.qml, and from the nested page emit the signals? More there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73218005/how-to-emit-signal-from-nested-qml-page-to-python

Comment: @WITC I provided an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73277234/12691808 just on your question page.